# is it possible to test an IAP refund(or any other apple sever notification) in sandbox environment

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am develop apple IAP(In App Purchase), I had complete query product-->purchase product-->verify receipt-->complete purchase workflow. Finally I want to test the refund workflow, Now I have complete the server side code and config the server notification callback url in apple connect.

But how to trigger apple notification? I am searching from internet, no one talk about this. I have read some questions to ask test refund test before 4+ years. is it possible to test apple server notification on 2021 A.C? Only on production environment could test the server notification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't manually trigger a S2S(Server to Server).

What you can do though, is purchasing in sandbox, let it renew, upgrade/downgrade and cancel a subscription. The associated S2S will be sent by Apple.

But others S2S (like REFUND, REVOKE) will never be sent and you won't be able to test it before production (same goes with the grace period for example).

Comment: Why apple did not support all events in test environment? It is complex or other reason ?@romainsalles